# RPC and shared persistent data space

Tags: rpc, distributed-computing

I have a homework question that asks about an RPC system if we're using a shared persistent data space. Would having a shared persistent data space even change anything about the way you build an RPC system?

For example, if the client or server isn't available, there are different options to deal with that. If you also have a shared persistent data space, would this mean you should use it to store responses and requests if the client or server is unavailable? Would this be slow... is it unreasonable? Should I just ignore the shared persistent data space part of the question?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of race conditions and response times when writing shared data via rpc calls.

"In the traditional RPC model, a client is blocked in a remote procedure call until the call returns." see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

Using synchronious rpc calls, you have a problem with the server responsiveness but not with race conditions, using asynchronious rpc calls it's vice versa.